Howto set a js value for an input
very simple question, I want to dynamically generate a uuid.v4() as the value attribute of an input :
<input type="text" id="token" value=uuid.v4()>

I tried this right after the input :
<script>document.getElementById("token").value=uuid.v4()</script>

but it's not better.
Thanks

Are you getting any errors in the console…?


document.getElementById("myInput").value =uuid.v4()

How should this answer help the OP? The OP literally stated that he tried this ...
